# regular express in R: find nth occurrence and add some letter according to some condition

Tags: r, regex

I have a table in .tex and wanted to color the entries (or add marks) according to a rule defined by a matrix of the same size.

I feel that this could be done by finding nth occurrence of a regular expression and adding some letters according to some conditions defined by another matrix. But I got stuck with the coding... Can anyone help me with the regular expression?

A simple example is:

Input table:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] 
\begin{tabular}{ccc} 
1 &  2 &  3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Input matrix that defines the color:

| red | black | black |
| --- | --- | --- |
| black | black | blue |

Output table:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] 
\begin{tabular}{ccc} 
\textcolor{red}{1} &  2 &  3 \\
4 & 5 & \textcolor{blue}{6} \\
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to play the regex-game with something like this. It appears that you are creating this `tabular` table and you have the data that goes into it, I suggest it is far better (safer, faster, reproducible, programmable, readable, maintainable, ...) to address formatting when the table is created instead. There are several enhanced LaTeX-table packages for R, including `gt`, `kableExtra`, `gtsummary` (there are more).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea, as I said in my comment. But here's one method:

```r
### highlight just the contents *between* and not including the `tabular` lines
vec <- Filter(nzchar, unlist(strsplit(readLines("clipboard"), "\\\\")))
vec
# [1] "1 &  2 &  3 " "4 & 5 & 6 "  
m <- matrix(c("red", "black", "black", "black", "black", "blue"), nr=2, byrow=T)
m
#      [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
# [1,] "red"   "black" "black"
# [2,] "black" "black" "blue" 

result <- Map(function(st, col) {
  ifelse(col == "black", st, sprintf("\\textcolor{%s}{%s}", col, st))
}, strsplit(vec, "\\s*&\\s*"), asplit(m, 1))
result <- paste0(paste(
  sapply(result, paste, collapse = " & "),
  collapse = "\\\\\n"
), "\\\\")
cat(result, "\n")
# \textcolor{red}{1} & 2 & 3 \\
# 4 & 5 & \textcolor{blue}{6 }\\
```

(If you get a warning about `incomplete final line found on 'clipboard'`, that is safe to ignore. This use of `readLines("clipboard")` works on windows, I think it works on linux, you may need to use `pbCopy` or something on macos.)

Comment: DaisyYu, does this work for you?